# javax eval function not working I don't know why it's turning to the exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, eval, calculation

my script is kinda long so I pasted it on a website. Click the link below to view the script:

Link - https://dpaste.org/K0mc

There line 474 the `eval()` function not working it directly turning to the `Exception`

And I was passing a String value through `eval()` and the value like `"10 + 10"` please help

Comment: Please [edit] the post and include the **relevant** code. --- "*... it directly turning to the `Exception`...*" - Please [edit] the post and include the stack trace. --- "*please help*" - Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: What text are you actually passing to the `eval()` function?  It's not clear from your code.  I suggest you use your debugger to find the value that you're passing.  You may be able to tell what's wrong by looking at it directly.  If not, you could try adding it to this question.  As it is though, this question is unanswerable, so I've voted to close it.

Comment: It's a String value and the value like "10 + 10"